# Is boiling once more effective than boiling twice half the amount?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, everyday-life, water, phase-transition

In a real-life (non-ideal) situation, is boiling 1 litre of water in a kettle the same as boiling two times 500 millilitres in terms of consumed energy? In the latter, I assume the kettle is still hot from the previous boiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuition tells me that the only difference is due to heat loss while at high temperature. Assuming the same kettle the rate of loss from the kettle should be the same at given temperature. Because the smaller volume heats faster, I think it will spend less time at high temperature, and the net energy loss will be less.

I calculated an equation by integrating the equation for rate of temperature increase and obtained a logarithmic law for the amount of time taken. This confirmed my intuition, although there is not a great deal in it. (I did not attempt to fit realistic numbers, but the numbers are not relevant to the principle.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes exactly twice the amount of time then there is no difference. If you allow the kettle to cool down in between boiling 1 litre at once is more efficient. If you don't need 100 degrees but say 80 degrees only, you can save more by switching of early, so be pound wise...